# How to install Fastlane on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, fastlane

I'm new with Fastlane, I want to use it with my android app. I use Ubuntu 14.04 as OS.
I want to know how can I install it on ubuntu 14.04, and if I should use a docker or there's another method?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need ruby installed. Have you done that yet? After that you can use `gem` to `install` it.

See [installing Ruby on Ubuntu](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#apt).

See [installing fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#installing-fastlane).